# add radiobuttonlist to ascx

Tags: c#

i want to add a rsionbuttonlist to my ascx web control.. i keep getting an error that ineed to put the radionbuttonlist inside a  tag. is there a way around this?

```
"
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="step2.ascx.cs" Inherits="ascx_step2" %>
<div id="step2" runat="server">
     <asp:RadioButtonList id="answers" runat="server">       
     </asp:RadioButtonList>
<div>
"
```

in the code behind:

```
 ListItem item = new ListItem("a", "a")
   answers.Items.Add(item);
```

the error :

control "ctl_00..." of type radiobutton must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server

Comment: Can you post your markup and the exact error message youre getting?

Comment: If the error is at runtime, ensure that you are correctly including the control in your containing page.

Comment: !And that you have appropriate closing tags in your markup.

Answer (score 0):

```
<table>
    <tr>
       <td>
            Drag and drop from the tool box, in UI mode
       <td>
      </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: You are assuming here that the OP is using tables for the layout, which is not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the control is added to the containing page (containing a form element) properly and the radio button list is declared correctly:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblSomeRadioButtonList" runat="server">
  <asp:ListItem Text="Something" Value="True"/>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

Comment: its inside a usercontrol so i cannot add form tag

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few things to check:

- Perhaps this was just a typo, but your example .ascx markup has a leading and trailing quote that does not belong in a real .ascx file.
- Ensure that your user control is placed on a page within the form tag.

MyPage.aspx:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
      <myprefix:MyUserControl ID="mycontrol" runat="server" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

- If you are dynamically adding your user control to the page in code-behind, make sure you are adding it to something that is already inside the correct form tag.